# Why the code not bale to run the function in other php file?

Tags: php, post, get, sweetalert

I have encounter 1 problem when sending message to other php file and show success notification message with sweet alert. Initially, the program is expect to go to other php file(index.php) with message sending with url and run the php code in index.php(The page if there is no error found in login function.php).Login function php is where all the function for checking for login.php. Index.php is where user successful login into the system.

**In login function.php i have this code**

```
 header("Location: " .$path."/order/index.php?page=1&login_status=success");
```

**In bottom part of index.php, i have included php code below.**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login_status']) && $_GET['login_status'] == 'success'){
    echo "<script>
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Welcome to MyCommerse',
    })
    </script>";
    echo "<script>
    history.replaceState(null, '', location.href.split('&')[0]);
    </script>";
}
?>
```

When i run debugging with PHP Debug in visual studio code, the program stop at **header("Location: " .$path."/order/index.php?page=1&login_status=success");**. It does not run the coding in index.php.

Comment: What is your `$path`?

Answer (score 0):

As per your explanation, File2(`index.php`) can not cause any issue on File1(`function.php`)  as File1(`function.php`) is loading first and successfully executing code.

Ideally, code should have

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$page = "order/index.php?page=1&login_status=success";
header("Location: http://{$host}{$uri}/$page");
exit; // add exit here to terminate the script execution
```

double check your `$path` variable

Comment: thanks @Ravi will try to look into this. Will come to you again if I face any problem.

Comment: Hi @Ravi,yesterday i have tried the code u given and change them to your code and is not working. When i see at google console, the value ?page=1&login_status=success is passed through index.php but index.php couldnt run the php code below on index.php.

Comment: oh, that means you are getting to index.php. write `print_r($_GET)` in  index.php and check what are you are getting in an array.